# Reusable Implementation of the Publish-Subscribe Pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I've finished an implementation of what I believe the Publish-Subscribe pattern is for practice and possible use in personal projects even though this implementation is fairly similar to the Observer/Observable classes of the Java API.

I'm looking for a review of my code-style, JavaDoc usage, API usage, implementation of the pattern, tests, and just about anything else you can think of.

#### Radio:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Radio <Data> {
    /** A {@link HashMap} of events mapped to listening {@link Receiver Receivers}. */
    private final HashMap<String, Set<Receiver<Data>>> receivers = new HashMap<>();

    /**
    * Transmits an event without data.
    *
    * @param event
    *         The event to transmit.
    */
    public final void transmit(final String event) {
        if (event == null || event.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("A transmitted event cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        transmit(event, null);
    }

    /**
    * Transmits an event with data.
    *
    * @param event
    *         The event whose receivers are to be transmitted to.
    *
    * @param data
    *         The data to transmit to the {@link Receiver Receivers}.
    */
    public final void transmit(final String event, final Data data) {
        if (event == null || event.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The event cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        final Set<Receiver<Data>> receivers = this.receivers.get(event);

        if (receivers != null) {
            receivers.forEach(receiver -> receiver.receive(event, data));
        }
    }

    /**
    * Adds a receiver to an event.
    *
    * @param event
    *         The event to add a receiver to.
    *
    * @param receiver
    *         The receiver to add.
    */
    public final void addReceiver(final String event, final Receiver<Data> receiver) {
        if (event == null || event.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The event cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        if (receiver == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The receiver cannot be null.");
        }

        if (receivers.containsKey(event) == false) {
            receivers.put(event, new LinkedHashSet<>());
        }

        receivers.get(event).add(receiver);
    }

    /**
    * Removes a receiver from an event.
    *
    * @param event
    *         The event to remove a receiver from.
    *
    * @param receiver
    *         The receiver to remove.
    */
    public final void removeReceiver(final String event, final Receiver<Data> receiver) {
        if (event == null || event.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The event cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        if (receiver == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The receiver cannot be null.");
        }

        final Set<Receiver<Data>> receivers = this.receivers.get(event);

        if (receivers != null) {
            receivers.remove(receiver);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Removes all receivers from an event.
    *
    * @param event
    *         The event to remove receivers from.
    */
    public final void removeReceivers(final String event) {
        if (event == null || event.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The event cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        final Set<Receiver<Data>> receivers = this.receivers.get(event);

        if (receivers != null) {
            receivers.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Receiver:

```
public interface Receiver<Data> {
    /**
    * Receives data from a transmission.
    *
    * @param event
    *         The event that caused the transmission.
    *
    * @param data
    *         The received data.
    */
    void receive(final String event, final Data data);
}
```

#### RadioTest:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RadioTest {
    @Test
    public void transmitA() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.addReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
        radio.transmit("Test Event");

        Assert.assertEquals(receiver.getData(), null);
    }

    @Test
    public void transmitB() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.addReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
        radio.transmit("Test Event", null);

        Assert.assertEquals(receiver.getData(), null);
    }

    @Test
    public void transmitC() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.addReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
        radio.transmit("Test Event", "Hello");

        Assert.assertEquals(receiver.getData(), "Hello");
    }

    @Test
    public void transmitD() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.addReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
        radio.transmit("Other Event", "Hello");

        Assert.assertEquals(receiver.getData(), "");
    }

    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void removeReceiverA() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        radio.removeReceiver(null, null);
    }

    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void removeReceiverB() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        radio.removeReceiver("Test Event", null);
    }

    @Test
    public void removeReceiverC() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.removeReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
    }

    @Test
    public void removeReceiverD() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.addReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
        radio.removeReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
    }

    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void removeReceiversA() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        radio.removeReceivers(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void removeReceiversB() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        radio.removeReceivers("Test Event");
    }

    @Test
    public void removeReceiversC() {
        final Radio<String> radio = new Radio<>();
        final ReceiverTest receiver = new ReceiverTest();

        radio.addReceiver("Test Event", receiver);
        radio.removeReceivers("Test Event");
    }
}
```

#### ReceiverTest:

```
public class ReceiverTest implements Receiver<String> {
    private String data = "";

    @Override
    public void receive(final String event, final String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Receiver

- `Data` is a placeholder denoting a generic type. In Java, generics are pointed out with a single-letter literal (most often, `T`, `E` or `U`). The choice of `Data` is a bit misleading: one can easily understand that there is a type called `Data`, but indeed it is generic. Use a single letter name istead.
- `final` keywords with arguments in interface method declarations do not have much sense: the implementor may declare them as non final, it's up to him to decide. So you can avoid extra verbosity and declare the method as `void receive(String event, T data);`.

### Radio

- Same remark about the generic type: it's better to use a single-letter literal.
- The `receivers` field should be typed as `Map` (interface) instead of `HashMap` (implementation). Prefer interfaces to implementations where possible, especially for collections.
- There are possible name clashes in the calls `final Set<Receiver<Data>> receivers = this.receivers.get(event);`. Naming a local variable as a field of the parent object is not a crime, but is prone to errors and bugs.
- `if (receivers.containsKey(event) == false)` is the same thing as `if (!receivers.containsKey(event))`, but consider using the dedicated `receivers.putIfAbsent` instead of calling `containsKey`.

#### Args Validation

It is not optimal for many of the methods:

- there are code duplications. The checks should be extracted to a method like `ensureStringArgNotNullNotEmpty(String arg, String argName)`, which should be able to produce an exception message with the name of the argument.
- `event.isEmpty()` does not correspond to the meaning of the thrown exception. `event` is not null here, so why `NullPointerException` ?

I think that `IllegalArgumentException` is more appropriate for these validation checks.

If you still want to remain on `NullPointerException`, consider using one-liners with the standard `Objects.requireNonNull` call.

### RadioTest

All the tests are clean, nicely coded and respect the principle of one assertion per test case.

But

1. They are all poorly named.

Just compare the current naming:

```
transmitA();
transmitB();
```

with alternatives:

```
nullDataReturnedWhenTransmittingEventOnly();
nullDataReturnedWhenTransmittingEventWithNullData();
```

If something breaks, you'll easily find where the problem is, instead of decoding the meaning of `A` or `B`.

2. The tests methods named `transmit*` make assertions about `Receiver` instances. Shouldn't they be placed in `ReceiverJUnitTest` cases ?

Answer (score 1):

2 minor comments:

- Your code style is fairly "aggressive" (the technical term is offensive) in the sense that you're throwing an exception as soon as an error occurred. Especially for a pub/sub piece, which I would consider more infrastructure than client-side, I would be using more of a [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) approach.
- Pub/Sub usually means multi-threaded, in which case you should consider using the following classes (as well as the correct CAS/or atomic methods for those methods):

  - a ConcurrentHashMap instead of a HashMap
  - a ConcurrentSkipListSet instead of a LinkedHashSet